# How to avoid firebase database child value overwrite issue?

Tags: java, android-studio, firebase-realtime-database

The code is given below which adds sub-child under 'Contacts' by 'name' instead unique key.

```
String name = CName.getText().toString().trim();
DatabaseReference mDbRef = mDatabase.getReference().child("Contacts").child(name);
mDbRef.child("cname").setValue(dCName);
mDbRef.child("pcontact").setValue(dPContact);
mDbRef.child("pdesig").setValue(dPDesig);
mDbRef.child("pemail").setValue(dPEmail);
mDbRef.child("pmobile").setValue(dPMobile);
```

The purpose is to store contact details. The company name is captured in 'name' and added 'Contacts' as sub child. But whenever, I try to add a new person in the same company name, it overwrites the previous entry with new one.

Could you please help me how to overcome this issue to enable to add more person in same company name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to to use `push()` to generate a new unique location for the user.

```
String name = CName.getText().toString().trim();
DatabaseReference mDbRef = mDatabase.getReference().child("Contacts").child(name).push();
mDbRef.child("cname").setValue(dCName);
mDbRef.child("pcontact").setValue(dPContact);
mDbRef.child("pdesig").setValue(dPDesig);
mDbRef.child("pemail").setValue(dPEmail);
mDbRef.child("pmobile").setValue(dPMobile);
```

---

Unrelated, I recommend combining all the values into a map, and calling `setValue` only once:

```
String name = CName.getText().toString().trim();
DatabaseReference mDbRef = mDatabase.getReference().child("Contacts").child(name).push();
Map<String, Object> values = new HashMap<>();

values.put("cname", dCName);
values.put("pcontact", dPContact);
values.put("pdesig", dPDesig);
values.put("pemail", dPEmail);
values.put("pmobile", dPMobile);

mDbRef.setValue(values);
```

Having just a single write operation is more efficient, but also will make it easier to secure the database down the line.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It works the way I want. As I am new to programming, I need to learn more to write code more efficient way. Now having issue in picking back the value in firebase recycler adapter. My database reference was `mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Contacts")` Now it doesn't pick the value as it goes to sub-child 'name' which varies. Could you please tell me how to refer to get back the value to show it in my adapter? Adapter code is given below

Comment: `FirebaseRecyclerOptions<project> options = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<project>().setQuery(mDatabase, project.class).build();
FBRA = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<project, ProjViewHolder>(options) {
protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ProjViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull project model) {                 
holder.cpname.setText(model.getCname());                
holder.ccname.setText(model.getPcontact();`